# visual studio 2017: open AND build solution from a command line call

Tags: windows, visual-studio, command-line, visual-studio-2017

In visual studio 2017 (or probably any version) I want to open a solution in the IDE and start it building from the command line. IF the solution is already open then I just want it to start building (in the IDE).

So I can open the solution like this:

`devenv solution.sln`

Or I can build it like this:

`devenv /build solution.sln`

There is also this:

`devenv solution.sln /command ...`

But the documentation on what "commands" there are is very difficult to find out about... The example is some user made macro, but I assume there are other built in commands? - this may help...?

But I am not sure how to:

- Open a solution in the IDE and have it build straight away
- If its already open just get it to start building.

Is there some way to do this?

My use case is to kick off the build from within IBM Rhapsody. In MSVS2012 it supported a Rhapsody addin which did these tasks... but addins have been deprecated since 2013 so I can get Rhapsody to do what I want by re-writing its make file content - the makefile will just call a batch file script which will do the commands that I am trying to do in this question - and then Rhapsody plugin done :)

Comment: Why don't you use msbuild

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because that does not suit my use-case - which is to open my solution from within Rhapsody...

Comment: Well I don't really understand. You want to get devenv to drive msbuild, but it's no good to go straight to msbuild.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want it to **open** my solution in visual studio and also run the build (e.g. `devenv /build my_solution.sln`). This works, however when I run the script again it opens another instance of visual studio - I just want it to use the current instance to re-build (I try to explain this in paragraph 1 of my question) - is that making sense?, I can try to draw a block diagram or something... sorry if its not clear

Comment: I just don't understand why you feel that the goal is to drive Visual Studio. I thought the goal would be to compile your code. I guess I am wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Its more because of Rhapsody. We use that to generate state machine code. But we use MSVS IDE to edit everything else. So we have both open. Normally we start with Rhapsody then we (as a convenience) open the solution from Rhapsody. Rhapsody used to have a plugin to do this - but visual studio no longer supports plugins (they use something else now, which Rhapsody don't support). I am trying to emulate part of what that plugin used to do. Rhaps drives MSVS and MSVS drives Rhaps so that the two can work side by side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually note that:

1. `devenv solution.sln` only opens a solution in a new VS IDE instance.
2. `devenv /build solution.sln` only builds projects that have changed since the last build without opening VS IDE. To build all projects in a solution, use /rebuild instead.

So, if you want to

> Open a solution in the IDE and have it build straight away

you should run the two commands consecutively:

```
devenv solution.sln  
devenv /rebuild solution.sln
```

Then at the second time use /rebuild only to avoid opening a new VS instance.

**Update**: you can make a  **.cmd** or **.bat** file contains the following:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq devenv.exe" /v | find /i "solution" 2>NUL
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto solution_is_running
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto solution_is_closed

:solution_is_running
devenv /rebuild solution.sln
goto:eof

:solution_is_closed
devenv solution.sln
devenv /rebuild solution.sln
goto:eof
```

Or use:

```
Taskkill /IM devenv.exe /F
devenv solution.sln  
devenv /rebuild solution.sln
```

Comment: lol....no, my question contains the question : ) ... I could string the two command together, that's easy. although I really want the project to build within the IDE. But what is not so easy is how do I determine if the solution is already open so that I don't re-open it? I could look for devenv.exe, but I might have multiple solutions open - which one is the one that I want (if any)? Also the taskkill is an interesting, but ultimately really bad, idea. What if I have done a load of work that is not yet saved...boom, taskkill!...oh, where is my work?

Comment: hmmm.... tell you what - this looks much better, I will try this out on Monday. I know the bounty ends tomorrow, but dont worry, if the bounty rolls over and you're solution works I will re-do it and give it : )

Comment: yes, this works because the /v switch gives me the window title from which I can determine which project is open - I can take it from there!, thanks very much, nice find :)

Answer (score 0):

devenv solution.sln /Command "Build.RebuildSolution"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).